# Can someone illustrate what's linux device number's minor number exactly for?

Tags: linux, device-driver

> The minor number is used by the kernel
>   to determine exactly which device is
>   being referred to.

The above explanation is just two abstract, can someone illustrate?

Answer (score 3):

The major number identifies the device driver to use, the minor number indicates which device.  If you have multiple partitions, for instance, each gets its own minor:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jun  3 20:48 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Jun  3 20:48 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Jun  3 20:48 /dev/sda2
```

Minor 0 in this case is the raw drive, minor 1 is partition 1, minor 2 is partition 2, etc.  Not all devices use 0 as a special case, however.  The serial devices start their numbering at 0, where `/dev/tty0` is just the first (virtual) terminal device on the system:

```
crw--w---- 1 root tty  4, 0 Jun  3 20:48 /dev/tty0
crw------- 1 root root 4, 1 Jun  3 20:50 /dev/tty1
crw------- 1 root root 4, 2 Jun  3 20:50 /dev/tty2
crw------- 1 root root 4, 3 Jun  3 20:50 /dev/tty3
```

In either event, when the device file is opened the kernel will use the major number to determine which module will handle the file and passes the minor to the `open()` method of the `struct file_operations` structure that was registered with `register_chrdev()`.

Comment: The book I'm reading says `firstminor should be the requested first minor number to use; it is usually 0` in the function `int alloc_chrdev_region(dev_t *dev, unsigned int firstminor,unsigned int count, char *name);` , how can devices usually be 0 ?

Comment: Disks are usually not numbered with 0, but with other devices, there's a 0 at the first one: /dev/rfcomm0,/dev/fd0,/dev/lp0,...

Answer (score 0):

as in the language C ,counting starts from 0 ...it could be a sort of convention followed by driver writers ...after all everything in Linux is based upon C or to some extent C++.Its just a numbering scheme ..You can also start naming your devices from any number between 0 and 255,but please be carefull do not cross the 255 mark for minor numbers else you may overwrite the next available major number..hope this answer helps